# How to record video for Protractor end to end scripts

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I'm able to generates subtitles with each spec names in the video folder. But unable to record the video.
Can any one help where i'm going wrong.

My config file:

```
onPrepare: function () {
  var VideoReporter = require('protractor-video-reporter');

    VideoReporter.prototype.jasmineStarted = function() {
        var self = this;
        if (self.options.singleVideo) {
            var videoPath = path.join(self.options.baseDirectory, 'protractor-specs.mov');

            self._startScreencast(videoPath);

            if (self.options.createSubtitles) {
                self._subtitles = [];
                self._jasmineStartTime = new Date();
            }
        }
    };

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new VideoReporter({
        baseDirectory: path.normalize(path.join(__dirname, '../testresults/videos/')),
        createSubtitles: true,
        singleVideo: true,
        saveSuccessVideos : true,
        ffmpegCmd: path.normalize(path.join(__dirname,'../node_modules/ffmpeg-binaries/bin/ffmpeg.exe')),
        ffmpegArgs: [
            '-f', 'gdigrab',
            '-framerate', '24',
            '-video_size', 'wsxga',
            '-i', 'desktop',
            '-q:v','10',
        ]
    }));
```

};

Comment: Where are you running these? ie which OS?

Comment: I'm running scripts in windows 10

Comment: please include whole config file and the command how you start protractor